# How do I change color but keep tint in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, color-conversion, swatches

I have an illustration made of several parts. All parts are the same spot color (some Pantone color) but they are different in tint. I know that I can select them all and go to Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork, but I need to continue to use Pantone spot colors. If I select these colored parts and click a new Pantone spot color, it over-rides the original tint values.

Answer (score 3):

If your illustration has really *all parts the same spot color*, replace this color for the new one:

- At the **Swatches Panel**, click the *New Color* and holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Win click the *Old Color*
- From the Swatches Panel Options Menu choose **Merge Swatches**

[image]

Comment: You can also alt drag the swatch on top of the other.